# What is wrong with my interpretation of a normal distribution question?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I am trying to solve the [following testing problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-central-limit-theorem-1), which can be rephrased as:

A load of cargo contains 49 boxes where the weight of a box follows a distribution with mean µ = 205 pounds and standard deviation σ = 15 pounds.

What is the probability that all 49 boxes can be safely loaded onto the elevator which can transport a maximum of 9800 pounds.

---

Here are my thoughts: I need to find a the value of a cumulative distribution function $CDF(9800, µ_1, σ_1)$, where $µ_1 = 49 * µ$, $σ_1 = 49 * σ$. So I get the probability of 0.36, which is not correct.

Comment: @Augustin thanks you are right. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful, standard deviation of the sum is not the sum of the standard deviation, it is the square root of the sum of variances.